# Show a row on the last page of a paginated jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to make a hidden row visible when the last page of the datatable is clicked.How can I do this? I could not find the method to get the current page number and the last page number of Jquery Datatable pagination.

This is what I want to do,but I dont have any idea abt how to get current page and last page.

```
$( "#paginate_button" ).click(function() {     
if(.......){  //if clicked page number= last page
$( "#hidden_row" ).show();
else
$( "#hidden_row" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: seems interesting but we like to see the code where you have issues.

Comment: This is what I want to do,but I dont have any idea abt how to get current page and last page.   
    $( "#paginate_button" ).click(function() {     
    if(.......){  //if clicked page number= last page
    $( "#hidden_row" ).show();
    else
    $( "#hidden_row" ).hide();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, implement the wellknown [fnPagingInfo][1] "plugin". Eg add the following to your code :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings ) {
  return {
    "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
    "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
    "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
    "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
    "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
    "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
    "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
  };
}
```

Then, apply the if condition in fnDrawCallback  :

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
    var currentPage= this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;     
    if ((+currentPage + +1) == this.fnPagingInfo().iTotalPages) {
    $("#target_id").show();
    }else
    $("#target_id").hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,this is what I needed. And I used the fnDrawCallback function instead of the .click() function for the if condition.

Comment: gr8! But if you use `fnDrawCallback`, wont you get a lot of unnessecary calls to the function? It is a minor detail. You dont have to evaluate everytime on "back" or when filtering.

Comment: I have disabled filtering, and I also needed the check to be performed when number of entries on a page were changed from 10 to 100 for example,as in some cases that would cause all the entries to show on a single page.In this scenario,pagination buttons would not be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and that worked for me too. But, I had to put this way (the script must be loaded before the datatable):

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {

  "fnDrawCallback": function () {
      var currentPage= this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;     
      if ((+currentPage + +1) == this.fnPagingInfo().iTotalPages) {
        $("#target_id").show();
      }else{
        $("#target_id").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

*I would put it as a comment to the other answer but I don't have enought reputation.