# Hide Button From Last Row In A DataTable - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to `DataTable` and struggling. In my last column i have a 'Delete' button but i want to `hide` this for the 'Last Row Only'.

The issue i'm having is that i'm struggling, in fact have no idea on how to identify the last row.

I thought the code below may have worked to pull the `Data` returned but it doesn't.

```
var rowData = $('#existingRulesDataTable').DataTable().rows('.row:last' ).data();
```

Also tried

```
var rowData = $('#existingRulesDataTable').rows( '.row:last' ).data();
```

Below is part of the `Data` and some other functions i'm doing once the `rows` are populated with `Data`

```
"columns": [                                                        // Display JSON data in table
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "startTime" },
                { "data": "endTime" },
                { "data": "selectedDays" },
                { "data": "selectedDates" },
                { "data": "selectedMonths" },
                { "data": "timeRange" },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data) {
                        if (buttonclicked == 'Modify') {                        // Displays the radio button when 'Mod' clicked
                            return  '<label class="c-radio" style="margin-bottom: 0px">'
                                +   '<input type="radio" name="existingRuleActionRadioButton" value="option1">'
                                +       '<span class="fa fa-check"></span>'
                                +   '</label>';
                        } else if (buttonclicked == 'Delete') {                 // Displays the delete button when 'Del' clicked
                            return '<button name="deleteRuleButton" class="btn btn-danger" id="' + data.position + '">'
                                + '<i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: large"></i>'
                                + '</button>';
                        } else {
                            return ''; // Needed for the 'Add' button click
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (data.startTime == 'Anytime') {
                    $('td:eq(1)', row).attr('colspan', 2).css('text-align', 'center').html('All day');  // Adds COLSPAN attribute, centers the wording and changes it from 'Anytime'
                    $('td:eq(2)', row).css('display', 'none');                                          // Hides cell next to the cell with COLSPAN attribute
                }

                if (data.timeRange == '-w') {
                    $('td:eq(6)', row).html('Working hours');          // Changes text returned by JSON if '-w'
                } else if (data.timeRange == '-oo') {
                    $('td:eq(6)', row).html('Out of office hours');    // Changes text returned by JSON if '-oo'
                }

                var rowData = $('#existingRulesDataTable').DataTable().rows('.row:last' ).data();
                //var rowData = $('#existingRulesDataTable').rows( '.row:last' ).data();

                alert('rowData: ' + rowData.position)
            },
```

The button i want to hide is the part in `columns`

```
 return '<button name="deleteRuleButton"
```

I just need the this `button` to be `hidden` for the last row

Comment: Isn't the purpose of your request not to let to remove all the rows from the table? If so, I would suggest another approach.

Comment: I don't know the full ins and outs of datatables, but you can check when rendering if you have the last row, eg : `if (row == $('#existingRulesDataTable').DataTable().row( ':last', { order: 'applied' } ))`  (with efficiencies applied) https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34427/get-last-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to always hide the last row's button, this saves you needing to ensure you call any additional javascript at the correct time.

```
#tableId tr:last-child button
```

If you have more than one button on the last row, then you can identify it with eg `.btn.btn-danger` or give it a more explicit class or use `[name=deleteRuleButton]`

Example using CSS:

```css
#existingRulesDataTable tr:last-child button {    
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id='existingRulesDataTable'>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><button>del</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><button>del</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><button>del</button></td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have `pagination` on the page, so it's removing the `button` from every last `row` on each page, i just need it to do this for the entire data rows returned, any idea how to sort please

Comment: Ok, there was no (obvious) mention of paging / the "very" last row across pages - this obviously won't work for that as this is an HTML/CSS solution, you'll need a solution within DataTables, such as tagging the *record* itself as the last record.

Comment: Yeh this was my bad, i should have stated i had `pagination` and only wanted it on the very last data row returned

Comment: No worries - should have guessed as it's datatables and that's one of the primary reasons for using datatables

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr:last` to find button with `name attribute` and hide that button.

```
$('#existingRulesDataTable tr:last').find("[name='deleteRuleButton']").hide(); //or you may use id or class when using find
```

**Note : You must call this after render datatable.**

Edit as per comment:

You can use custom function to extend `datatbale` default functionality. Check is it last page or not and if it's last page apply your condition.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings ) {
  return {
    "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
    "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
    "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
    "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
    "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
    "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
    "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
  };
}
```

And call like:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  "fncheckPage": function() {
    var Page = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
    if ((+Page + +1) == this.fnPagingInfo().iTotalPages)
      $('#existingRulesDataTable tr:last').find("[name='deleteRuleButton']").hide();
  }
});
```

Code check for last page taking from [this so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110837/965146) answer and modified as per your condition.

Comment: Please see my comment to the other reply.  I did try your solution but i couldn't get it working

Comment: How do i implement this, does it need to be referenced anywhere on the `DataTable`? This is my first time using them so no idea.  I can put my full code in my post if you'r like

Comment: After render datatable you can apply this code and  remove last line .

Comment: sorry to pester you but i have got round to trying to implement this ans still can get it to work as i'm unsure of where to add the code being new to `DataTables`. Any chance you could do a code snippet so i can see where i need to add the code please (e.g. a fiddle or just use my code provided so i can look, read and understand what your proposing for the fix